# How do I use beautifulsoup4 to select the last row in a table?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

Here is an example table I want to parse:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>1-1</td>
       <td>1-2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>2-1</td>
       <td>2-2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>3-1</td>
       <td>3-2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to locate the *last `tr` element in this table*.

What is the canonical way to do it in `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Do you any input samples ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 8):

There is *no direct way* to get the last row of a table. A common approach would be to *find all rows* and get the last one by index:

```
table = soup.find("table")
last_row = table("tr")[-1]
```

---

Note that, in an ideal world, if `BeautifulSoup` would have a full [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) syntax support, you could've used the [`last-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child):

```
soup.select_one("table tr:last-child")
```

But, unfortunately, this would result into a `NotImplementedError` at the moment.

Comment: specifically `:last-child` gives the error `NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.`